# Possible to install multiple Phonegap plugins for same function?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I need to use a barcode scanning plugin in my application that is targetting android, iOS and win7/8.

So far, I have a plugin that supports android and iOS and that is working fine.

I found another plugin that supports windows phones so I installed that as well.  Doing that broke the android plugin.

Is there a way to do this, or do I need to find a single barcode scanner plugin that supports all 3 platforms?

In case it matters, this is how I install the plugins:

```
phonegap plugin install <git repo URL>
```

**EDIT**

The plugins I am using:

- **Adroid/iOS**: https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git
- **Windows**:
  http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.bloxlab.barcodescanner

**EDIT 2**

Dawson Loudon posted this: github.com/dawsonloudon/BarcodeScanner.git

Which still works for my Android app.  Can't confirm win7/8 functionality.

Comment: Can't you just open a new project and install plugin to the new one, and add only windows phone platform!

Comment: What two plugins are you using? It would be possible to create a new plugin package that makes use of both, packaged as one.

Comment: I want to use PhoneGap for its intended purpose of writing the application once, though.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Updated my entry with the plugins I use. Is combining them into one plugin possible and the only way to do this?  Should multiple same-function plugins normally work, or is it something particular about these that don't work together?

Comment: It is most likely a namespace issue. If both plugins use the same JS namespace, it could cross streams. Most plugins play well together, but if they use generic JS calls like `Scanner.scan` they could conflict. It would be helpful to everyone to have one plugin that supported all three platforms. I'll take a look and see if it's something I could take on.

Comment: So looking at the code, both plugins are formatted the same. This does appear to be that one is overloading the other. However, because they are written the same, it would fairly easy to package them together as one plugin. I am going to try this out in the next hour or so.

Comment: So I compiled a new plugin from both. I don't have WP8 to test on, but I was able to install and run on Android. Can you uninstall both plugins and then run try this? `cordova plugin add https://github.com/dawsonloudon/BarcodeScanner.git`

Comment: Wow, excellent, thanks for posting this!  I also do not have a win device to test with, but I can confirm that my android app is still working with your plugin. Thanks again